# Offline report with D3, md and equations

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, markdown

Is it possible to create a single html page containing embedded [D3js](https://d3js.org/) charts, [CommonMark](https://commonmark.org/) text, and equations (e.g. [Katex](https://khan.github.io/KaTeX/) or [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/)) and have it all rendered the browser offline?

**Must have:**

- Works offline using modern Firefox/Chrome/Safari, after having
  downloaded a minimal number of JavaScript libs.
- No requirement for installing anything beyond the web browser.  So no local http server, Pandoc, R, Python etc.

**Should have:**

- Possible to write everything in a single html file, which opens in a normal modern browser.
- Good archival properties with minimal maintanence.

**Motivation:**

We work in a high security locked down IT environment and can’t install stuff, but we do have decent web browsers and can run javascript in them.

We routinely share small analytical reports internally, and are experimenting with delivering a directory containing

- an html file (with embedded JSON data), and
- downloaded D3 and [Underscore](https://underscorejs.org/) librariess

All the internal customer has to do is click on index.html. So far this has been very succesful, but we'd like to use markdown and equations too.

We are vaguely aware of data science workbook solutions like [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/) and [Observable](https://beta.observablehq.com/), but not sure that these meet our criteria.

**Clarification**

I know we can download libs and place them in a dir alongside index.html, but I'm not sure if a JavaScript library exists which can render the markdown and equations and write the results directly into the DOM.  And even if such a library exists, where in index.html would the markdown be written?  Is there some kind of html tag which can just hide a load of raw text which will be parsed by JS?

Comment: You can place all the needed js files next to the index.html and link to these files. Or you can place them in a parent sub directory so they can be used for all the different reports. Just use `../js/d3.v5.min.js` as the location of the js files.

Comment: @rioV8 thanks, have added clarification.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, it is possible. You'll either need Node app that will render static HTML pages or simple HTML page with embedded Javascript. Since all these libraries are available as UDM packages, I suggest 2nd option.

CommonMark CDN: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/commonmark
KaTeX CDN: https://khan.github.io/KaTeX/docs/browser.html

You'll only need to download these libraries and include them in page. KaTeX includes JS to convert simple text to rendered mathematical equation, you only need to give it text and element where to render equation: https://khan.github.io/KaTeX/docs/api.html. CommonMark is similar but it only gives you rendered HTML, you need to insert it with `element.innerHTML` yourself: https://www.npmjs.com/package/commonmark.